# Compare two random sequences in string with Regex

Tags: regex

How to check if two substrings of a string are equal.

The string can be constructed with a variable amount of random characters on the left side, a `=`, and a variable amount of random characters on the right side.

E.g.:

- `asdfasdf=123` -> shouldn't match
- `1=1` -> should match
- `1a23x=1a23x` -> should match
- `234!=!432` -> shouldn't match

Comment: "*I want to do X*" is not a question.

Comment: Thanks! I've rephrased the question to start with "How to do X" 

Comment: That doesn't really make it any better. It's still saying "write code for me".

Comment: Thanks for your input! How would you phrase the question?

Comment: Explain what problem you're trying to solve and why you're trying to use a regex for it. Show what you've tried and explain how it's failing.

Comment: Awesome feedback!  Thanks a lot! I'll try to keep that in mind. Btw: It would be great to write this feedback in your first comment. `"I want to do X" is not a question.` doesn't explain what's your problem with the question and makes this place feel not very friendly. Keep your good work up!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. I feel point 3 (homework questions) especially applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one `^([^=]+)=\1$` with back reference. Note that you need to enable the multiline flag (where `^` and `$` match start and end of each line).

It matches the second and third of your examples:

- Match 1
  Full match  `1=1`
  Group 1.    `1`
- Match 2
  Full match  `1a23x=1a23x`
  Group 1.    `1a23x`